# How can I get these body segments to seem less 'round'

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, geometry

So you'll see here that the top shoulder piece, even the top arm piece, has these nice edges that create the impression of pieces of denim.

[image]

But with the lower pieces you can see they sort of round out towards each edge creating a vertical [michelin man](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/a0/aa/afa0aa2b65dc57bcc5311678ac08874f.jpg) effect. How can I get them to sit more 'flat'?

I have shade smoothed the pieces but I've also marked all the edges of each piece as sharp and also used shift+E to create creases, thinking it would solve my issue, but it hasn't. Though it seems to work on the top parts!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with mark sharp and creases, but you should be able to fix that with additional edge loops along this parts, maybe share just this part of your object here (share the link): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: More subdivisions fixed it! thanks man!

Comment: do not subdivide, add edge loops along the one that you want to sharp

Comment: @moonboots yeah I went back and did that. Much better! thanks again!